# How to build the plugin with ant on mac

Tags: ant, intellij-idea

I found a salesforce plugin for intellij IDEA ([link](https://github.com/polyglot-mark/salesforce-plugin)), and now trying to install it. The problem is, i've never done this before. So according to instruction:

> ## How to build and install
>
> Until the plugin is released into the IntelliJ plugins repository, you
>   can following these instructions for manually building and installing
>   the plugin from GitHub:
>
> 1. Update the ANT script salesforce-plugin-xml with the location of your IntelliJ IDEA install 
>      `<!--property name="idea.path" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.2"/-->
>      <property name="idea.path" value="/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13.app"/>`
> 2. Execute the 'package' target of the ANT script - this will create a salesforce-plugin-#.#.zip file in the out directory
> 3. Go into IntelliJ IDEA settings under Plugins and select "Install plugin from disk".  Select the zip file and click Ok.

I downloaded a project from github, added path to idea to salesforce-plugin.xml. Then i realized that i don't have an ant to build it. I installed homebrew, installed ant, checked the version (ant appeared, ok).
Then i stuck. I tried different combinations, how to package the plugin, The last attempt is when i changed salesforce-plugin.xml to build.xml and wrote in terminal:

```
ant package build.xml
```

got:

> Buildfile: /Users/cooler/Downloads/salesforce-plugin-master/build.xml
>
> BUILD FAILED
>   /Users/cooler/Downloads/salesforce-plugin-master/build.xml:36: taskdef
>   class com.intellij.ant.Javac2 cannot be found  using the classloader
>   AntClassLoader[]

Can you help me please to do this in right way!?

BTW, i use Mavericks

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac, you need to add /Contents to the root path of the IDEA installation. For  example:

```
<property name="idea.path" value="/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents"/>
```

Comment: ok, it helped me to do a one more step further. :)

it says:
   [javac2] 16 errors
   [javac2] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
/Users/cooler/Downloads/salesforce-plugin-master/build.xml:89: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: This is an error in the Ant build script; the target for the JPS plugin does not include the necessary dependencies. You should try building the plugin from the IntelliJ IDEA project, not by using Ant. (Simply open the project in IntelliJ IDEA and execute "Prepare Plugin Module for Deployment"). Also, in general it's a good idea to contact the plugin author for questions related to a specific plugin, and not to post the questions on the World Wide Web.

Answer (score 1):

When generating ant build scripts:

```
build -> generate ant build 
-> check "use current idea instance for idea.home property"
```

Re-generate the ant build scripts.  Now the build should work propertly.